# помогите с кодом многопоточности куда вставить условия sleep

Tags: java, многопоточность

По обслуживанию клиентов в банке работает электронная очередь. Всего четыре кассира. Клиенты подходят к тому кассиру, который освободился. У каждого кассира своя средняя скорость обслуживания одного клиента ({2 мин.}, {2,5 мин.}, {2,4 мин.} и {3 мин.}, соответственно). Всего кассирам надо обслужить {150} клиентов. Необходимо разработать многопоточное приложение, которое позволяет сделать следующее:

a) вводятся все данные, отмеченные в условии задачи как {..};

б) выводится общий результат – общее время, за которое все клиенты будут обслужены;

в) количество клиентов, которое обслужит каждый кассир

```
class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(4);
    for (int i = 0; i< 150 ; i++)
        new Person (sem, i).start();
  }
 class Person extends Thread{
Semaphore sem;
int num = 0;
int id;
Person(Semaphore sem, int id)
{
    this.sem = sem;
    this.id = id;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        sem.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Клиент" + id + "пошел ");
    try {
        sleep(1200);
        sleep (1500);
        sleep(1440);
        sleep(1800);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sem.release();
    num++;
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

1. Вам надо завести каждому кассиру (классу `Person`) его скорость в виде миллисекунд задержки
2. Во время `run()` выставить `sleep()` равный его скорости
3. Задания реализовать в виде `SynchronousQueue` из которого брать элемент/задание через `poll()`

```
    SynchronousQueue<Integer> queue = new SyncronousQueue();
    for(int i = 0; i < 150; i++) //готовим очередь
        queue.put(i);  
    class Person extends Thread {
       int number; //количество заданий
       int delay;
       SynchronousQueue queue;
       Person(SyncronousQueue queue, int delay) {
           this.number=0;
           this.queue = queue;
           this.delay = delay;
       }
     
       @Override
       public void run() {
          while(true) {
             sleep(delay);
             Integer task=queue.poll(); //берем задания
             if (task == null)  
                break; //если очередь пуста завершаем работу
             number++;
          }
       }
    }
```